# Storing multiple values on Principle

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, spring-security, oauth

I'm using the Principle to store the current user id,

**Storing**

```
   val principalExtractor: (MutableMap<String, Any?>) -> Any? = { params ->
        val session = params.get("session") as MutableMap<String, Any?>
        val user = session.get("user") as MutableMap<String, Any?>
        user.get("email")
    }
```

**Usage**

```
@GetMapping("{userId}/activationWidgetUrl")
    fun getActivationWidgetUrl(principal: Principal, authentication: Authentication, @PathVariable userId: String): ActivationWidgetResponse? {

   let id = principal.name
}
```

**Issue:**
I am facing a situation where I need more details from the session, for example: -companyId-.

I would like to store a User object on the principle instead of just a string, but principle.name returns string by default.

**Question:**
How can I store an object on principle (Subclass?), or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by using **Authentication**.

**principalExtractor**

```
val principalExtractor: (MutableMap<String, Any?>) -> Any? = { params ->
        val session = params.get("session") as MutableMap<String, Any?>
        val user = session.get("user") as MutableMap<String, Any?>
        val mapper = ObjectMapper()
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
        val userDetails = mapper.convertValue(user, UserDetails::class.java)
        userDetails
    }
```

**usage**

```
@GetMapping("{userId}/activationWidgetUrl")
    fun getActivationWidgetUrl(authentication: Authentication, @PathVariable userId: String): ActivationWidgetResponse? {

       (authentication.principal as UserDetails).let { userDetails ->
            let id = userDetails.id
        }

}
```